# Persisting a single UISearchBar instance across 4 separate UITableViews

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uisearchbar

I'm in the midst of an iPhone app that needs to have 4 separate `UITableView` objects sharing access to one `UISearchBar` in the first section and first row of the aforementioned `UITableView` objects.

I have tried to offset the `UITableView`'s frame by 44 pixels, then adding the search bar as a subview of my `UIViewController`'s `view`. That works, but I cannot use the table index to scroll up to the search bar, since it is not a cell in the tableview. I need to have the search bar in the table view itself.

My goal is to have the same `UISearchBar` in the first section of multiple tableviews.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already mentioned, you might want to put the search bar in the `tableHeaderView` property of `UITableView`, which will put it at the top of the table without having to do the manual positioning.  I'm not sure how this works with indexing, though.

As for sharing a `UISearchBar`, I can't think of a good reason to instead of having one for each table view--the memory difference should be negligible, and setting and unsetting the delegate and whatnot could be a serious hassle.  Was there a particular reason you wanted to share the search bar?  If you want persistence, you can save the search bar text in `viewWillDisappear` and set it in `viewWillAppear`.

If you really want to put the search bar in the first cell, rather than the table header, you could do something like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = //etc, normal cell creation

    if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0) {
        [cell addSubview:self.searchBar];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

But putting a search bar in a table header is much more common, and much easier to manage.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply add the UISearchBar as the header view of each tableView as you switch between them.

```
[oldTableView setTableHeaderView:nil];
[newTableView setTableHeaderView:searchBar];
```

Of course, it's entirely possible that I've misunderstood what you're trying to do.  If that's the case, please elaborate.